# decltype of qualified-id denoting class member with `const T` vs. `T` in nested-name-specifier

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constants, decltype

Shall the static assertion in the code below fire?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

struct S { int i; };
using CS = const S;

static_assert(is_same_v<decltype((CS::i)), decltype((S::i))>);
```

Clang and MSVC are fine with it, GCC thinks that the assertion fires, because the type denoted by `decltype((CS::i))` is `const int&` and the type denoted by `decltype((S::i))` is `int&`: https://godbolt.org/z/5MqPX_. (**UPD:** as it is disclosed in the comments, `static_assert(is_same_v<decltype(CS::i), decltype(S::i)>);` is accepted by all three compilers https://godbolt.org/z/V5y-tD, but I'm interested in the wording which guarantees this).

[basic.type.qualifier]/1 seem to only guarantee that `T` and `const T` have the same object representation and alignment, but not that `const T`'s members has the same cv-qualification as the corresponding members of `T`.

Damn, if go 100% pedantic mode: I don't even think that the Standard requires that lookup in `const T` shall find a member named `N`, if `T` has such member. `const T` can haz `c_N` in place of `N` and has the same object representation and alignment requirement as `T` (assuming `c_N` is of `const decltype(T::N)` type). I don't find the word "version" in [basic.type.qualifier]/1 to have any normative meaning/obligation.

INB4 you point me to C++11/C++14/C++17's [class.name]/5 saying

> If a *typedef-name* that names a cv-qualified class type is used where a *class-name* is required, the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

*nested-name-specifier* doesn't require *class-name* (the grammar allows both *class-name* and *typedef-name*). [class.derived]'s *base-clause* (→ *base-specifier-list* → *base-specifier* → *class-or-decltype*) does (the grammar doesn't allow *typedef-name*). Anyway, the sentence cited above has been removed in C++20 by [P1131R2](http://wg21.link/p1131r2) and the wording about cv-qualifiers ignore went to [class.derived], the only place where it apply (in the list of base classes in a class definition).

Comment: if you only use one layer of parentheses, all three compilers pass: https://godbolt.org/z/V5y-tD So the problem shouldn't be the member itself

Comment: @L.F. I know that one layer is fine. But what in the Standard guarantees that it shall be fine?

Comment: I think the intent at least is that members remain the same when cv-qualifiers are added, but the wording isn't clear.  Maybe we need an issue for this ..

Comment: @L.F. will it be editorial?..

Comment: Given the discord among compilers, I guess the issue isn't "obvious" enough to classify as editorial, so ...

Comment: @L.F. I think it is just GCC's bug that `is_same_v<decltype(CS::i), decltype(S::i)> != is_same_v<decltype((CS::i)), decltype((S::i))`, this seem to be orthogonal to the question about the value of `is_same_v<decltype(CS::i), decltype(S::i)>`.

Comment: [basic.lookup]: "Name lookup associates the use of a name with a set of declarations ([basic.def]) of that name." Since `int i;` is the only declaration of `i`, only that declaration can possibly be found. (I can't find any evidence that suggests that compilers are permitted to synthesize a declaration in this case.)